# How to get the dictionary value after post request

Tags: python-3.x

```
import request


p = s.post(url, data=post_json_data,
          headers=headers)

posted_response = p.text

print(posted_response["message"])`

if posted_response["message"] == "Job added":
            print("Success")`
```

My posted_response = {"message":"Job added"}

Unable to get the value posted_response["message"]. Is there any solution to get value from dictionary after post request is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `posted_response = p.text` to `posted_response = p.json()`.
Hope it can help.
Best regards.